# Why can we apply Fubini's theorem here?

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral

Let $f : \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a measurable function define the function  $t \mapsto \lambda_f(t) = \mathcal L\{ x : \vert f(x) \vert > t\}$ where $\mathcal L$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$. Then we have the following

> Let $p > 1, f \in L^p$ then
>   $$ \int \vert f(x)\vert^p dx = p \int_0^\infty t^{p-1} \lambda_f(t) dt.$$

The proof is as follows:
define $$ \phi(x,t) = \begin{cases} 1  \quad \vert f(x)\vert > t \\0  \end{cases} $$

and

\begin{align*}
p \int_0^\infty t^{p-1} \lambda_f(t) \; dt &= p \int_0^\infty t^{p-1} \int_{\mathbb R^n} \phi(x,t)\; dx \; dt \\
&= p \int_{\mathbb R^n} \int_0^{\vert f(x)\vert}t^{p-1} dt \; dx \\
&= \int_{\mathbb R^n} \vert f(x)\vert^p dx.
\end{align*}

If we apply fubini then $t^{p-1} \phi(x,t)$ is integrable on $\mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb R^n$. Why is this the case ? Similarly how do we know that $t^{p-1}\lambda_f(t)$ is integrable on $\mathbb R^+$ ?

Comment: $\phi$ is non-negative so we can apply Tonelli's theorem. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_function)

Comment: @Masacroso Being positive and measurable is sufficient to switch order of integration ? So this proof is valid even if $f$ is not in $L^p$ ?

Comment: yes, when the measure is $\sigma$-finite (in particular the Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-finite). Read the wikipedia article for details. Also Tonelli-Fubini's theorem is slightly more general than Fubini, you can read about it the cited wikipedia article

Comment: @Digitalis An outline of the reason that non-negativity and measurability is enough is this; If you want to prove something like Fubini's theorem then you first prove it for simple functions, then you use the monotone convergence theorem to extend to measurable non-negative functions and as a result you get it for integrable things by decomposing into positive and negative parts. So along the way to proving it for integrable things it was crucial we get it for non-negative things.